# Is there a way to tell the delphi ide to insert the event handler stub at the end of the class?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe5

When I double click on an event entry in the Object Inspector (events tab), Delphi creates an event handler stub. It seems that the event handler gets inserted in the class in the alphabetical order of the method names. Is it possible to tell it to add the event handler at the end of the class? I didn't find any setting related to this.

Thanks

Comment: No. :-) There was a previous complaint in the Delphi forums on CodeGear in an earlier version about the IDE always putting the event handler at the end of the unit, and a feature request was posted in QC about changing that to make it alphabetical. Enough users voted on that post that it was incorporated into the Code Editor, and then there were complaints in the forums about it not being optional. The alternatives were never made part of the IDE. (Posting as a comment because I don't have links to the discussions or QC posts available.)

Comment: (continued) If you use Ctrl+Shift+Up/DownArrow to navigate between the declaration and implementation, it doesn't really seem like it would be an issue, however.

Comment: Alphabetical really sucks. It's a lame way to organise code. You want to see related methods close to each other.

Comment: @David: I didn't say *I* voted for it. :-) I'd suspect many upvoted the "feature request" at the time, and not many bothered to complain about it. I don't find it an issue; I declare it where I want in the interface, use Ctrl+Shift+C to create the implementation shell, and then cut/paste that shell where I want it (or leave it alone, and just use Ctrl+Shift+Up/DnArrow to navigate.

Comment: @Ken I wasn't meaning to imply that. It was a comment on the feature. And I do like you. Drop a bookmark. Ctrl+Shift+C, select, Ctrl+X, move to bookmark, Ctrl+V. The reason alphabetical sucks so hard is that when I do this with multiple methods, I have to hunt around for the empty stubs because they are scattered all over the unit. That's fundamental problem.

Comment: @KenWhite: Please post your message as an answer and I will flag it as answered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree; to circumvent, I've grown accustomed to writing the method implementations first, in the order I want, then use Ctrl+Shift+C to add them to the interface. (And then still reorder them there, but that's less hunting ;)